# Power BI Activities Log REST API Get Access Token

Tags: python, azure, powerbi, azure-api-apps, powerbi-api

I have been going crazy trying to pull activity logs from the Power BI Rest API. I can do it using this "try it" method from Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/getactivityevents

I have to login to use this tool and then I get a bearer JWT token that is valid for 1 hour, and can be used in the header of subsequent get requests inside scripts. However the token expires after 1 hour, and I have to relogin to get a new token and update my script. I'm trying to retrieve a JWT token every time it expires without having to login via a GUI. This is to basically automate getting logs from Power BI to send to a security application for analysis. On the Azure/Power BI side, I have registered a Native app using this link https://dev.powerbi.com/Apps. On the Azure app registrations I have given the app all API permissions.

I have some sample python code using the adal library that I'm trying to get working here.Powershell solutions would also be acceptable I guess, but I prefer using python.

```py
import adal
import requests
import json
import pandas


authority_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common'
resource_url = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
client_id = 'my client ID'
client_secret = 'my client secret'
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority=authority_url,
                                     validate_authority=True,
                                     api_version=None)

# get JWT access token without having to log in
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_url, client_id, client_secret)

access_token = token.get('accessToken')
logs_request_url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime=%272021-02-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%27&endDateTime=%272021-02-20T23%3A59%3A59.000Z%27"

header = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url=logs_request_url, headers=header).content
logs_request = json.loads(response)
# Power BI Activity Logs
print(logs_request)
```

This code gets me an empty response. If I paste the access_token generated when I logged in using the "try it" tool, it works. I'm trying to avoid manually logging in if possible, because this script would run as a scheduled task. I would appreciate any assistance on this, as I'm going crazy trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you have granted the necessary permission for the app.

You would need to enable the below setting (*Allow service principals to use read-only Power BI admin APIs*) at the Power Bi tenant level before using the API :

- Log into the Power BI admin portal.

[image]

- Access the tenant settings.
- Under Admin API settings, you will see Allow service principals to
  use read-only Power BI admin APIs.

[image]

- Enable the above setting.

You can refer to this article for a detailed instructions. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/read-only-apis-service-principal-authentication

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. I have enabled the above setting to allow service principals to use read-only Power BI admin APIs.  I'm still getting an empty response when I perform a get request to https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents. I'm adding in the start and end dates as url parameters also, as seen above. Are my resource url and authority url correct?

Comment: So I changed the authority url to this, 

authority_url =f 'https://login.microsoftonline.com' + '/tenantID'

And now I'm getting a "API is not accessible for application" error

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but your startdate/enddate query params don't look correct to me - they should be formatted like:

```
activityevents?startDateTime='2022-12-02T05:51:30.0000000Z'&endDateTime='2022-12-02T15:51:30.0000000Z'
```

I have a notebook that writes to a Fabric lakehouse using this API and that's how the URLs are formatted: https://github.com/klinejordan/fabric-tenant-admin-notebooks/blob/main/Fabric%20Admin%20Activities.ipynb